# Coin Change Leetcode C#

Tags: c#, recursion, dynamic-programming

I'm looking to implement Coin Change problem (https://leetcode.com/problems/coin-change) using Recursion and so far have the solution below. The problem seems to work correctly except when:

```
int[] coins = {2};
int k = 3;
```

Output is: -2147483648

Expected output is: -1

Below is the solution:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] coins = {2};
            int k = 3;

            Console.WriteLine(Coin_Change(k, coins));


        }
        public static int Coin_Change(int amount, int[] coins) {

            if (amount == 0) {
                return 0;
            }

            if (amount < 0) {
                return -1;
            }

            int minSteps = int.MaxValue;
            for (int i = 0; i < coins.Length; i++)
            {
                if (coins[i] <= amount)
                {
                    minSteps= Math.Min(minSteps, 1 + Coin_Change(amount - coins[i], coins));
                }

            }
           
            return minSteps;
        }
```

How do I extend the solution above to handle this case ?

Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

To overcome cases like that, you keep an additional check.

Sample Code:

```
public class Solution {
    int max = 100000008;
    int _go(int[] coins, int amount) {
        if (amount == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (amount < 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        int minSteps = max;
        for (int i = 0; i < coins.Length; i++) {
            if (coins[i] <= amount) {
                minSteps = Math.Min(minSteps, 1 + _go(coins, amount - coins[i]));
            }

        }
        return minSteps;
    }
    public int CoinChange(int[] coins, int amount) {
        int minStep =  _go(coins, amount);
        return minStep >= max ? -1 : minStep;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've taken a user defined max value. It's because if you take INT_MAX value as your initial answer, then try to add something with that and try to keep it in another int variable, it'll cause you overflow.

My given code will give you correct output for which you're supposed to give -1 as output (cases when you can't make target value with given coins).

But all test cases will not pass using this approach. You'll get TLE cause you haven't stored any result.

This is a classic DP problem. Check following resources to learn more about DP.

[Coin Change Problem | Dynamic Programming](https://www.codesdope.com/course/algorithms-coin-change/)

[Understanding The Coin Change Problem With Dynamic Programming](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-the-coin-change-problem-with-dynamic-programming/)

[Coin Change | DP](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/coin-change-dp-7/)